# Stop IIS while using Xampp (Windows 10 - conflicts of ports)?

Tags: iis, xampp, windows-10

In Windows 10 IIS and Xampp use the same port (80), I've learned. I know how to change port in Xampp, but I'd prefere to stop IIS while using Xampp. On my old computer with Windows 10 I went to task manager > services and stopped World Wide Web Services by rightclicking. On my new computer with Windows 10, I can't seem to find World wide web services on that spot. Can it be named something else, according to language (swedish - though before on the old computer it was named as mentioned)? Any other way (in simple steps, please - beginner!) to stop IIS using the port, without disabling the IIS alltogether? (might want to learn how to use it later on)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is used by default with many web servers (here IIS and Apache which is bundled inside XAMPP).

The default web site created with IIS uses port 80. If you don't want to use this default web site (absolutely no harm and no data loss!), you can delete it by running the following command in inetsrv directory (path would generally be C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv).

```
appcmd delete site "Default Web Site"
```

Or you can change the port for the default web site in IIS, with:

```
appcmd set site /site.name: "Default Web Site" /+bindings.protocol='http',bindingInformation='*:8000:']

appcmd set site /site.name: "Default Web Site" /-bindings.protocol='http',bindingInformation='*:80:']
```

(8000) is for instance, use any high number you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As mentioned, I'm a beginner... In the prompt: "'appcmd'is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" - seems I have use yet an other command?

Comment: Well it seems like it did the trick anyway, because now it's working with Xampp in port 80! Thanks a lot, appreciate it! ;o)

Comment: If you have IIS installed on your machine, then appcmd should have been there.. strange..